# wget send $_GET data instead of $_POST data?

Tags: wget

I know that I can run `wget --post-data=key=value`, but is there a way to send `$_GET` data instead? Such as through `get-data`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET data will be transmitted via the url. Like this:

```
wget http://your.server.net/?key=value
```

You can refer to [RFC 2616](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt)

Comment: Ah! This was such a stupid question now that I think about it!